# Python SUDS Error - SAXParseException

Tags: python, soap

Does anyone know why I would get a `"<unknown>:1:0: syntax error"` from a python suds call when the response looks like this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Body>
    <external.bz1:reply xmlns:abn.types="uri:abn.types.asic.gov.au" xmlns:bn.types="uri:bn.types.asic.gov.au" xmlns:business.document.header.types="uri:business.document.header.types.asic.gov.au" xmlns:external.bz1="uri:external.bz1.asic.gov.au" xmlns:fss.types="uri:fss.types.asic.gov.au" xmlns:types="uri:types.asic.gov.au">
      <business.document.header.types:businessDocumentHeader>
        <business.document.header.types:messageType>bnLodgeApplication</business.document.header.types:messageType>
        <business.document.header.types:messageReferenceNumber>1</business.document.header.types:messageReferenceNumber>
        <business.document.header.types:messageVersion>1</business.document.header.types:messageVersion>
        <business.document.header.types:senderId>ASIC</business.document.header.types:senderId>
        <business.document.header.types:senderType>GOVT</business.document.header.types:senderType>
        <business.document.header.types:messageEvents>
          <business.document.header.types:messageEvent>
            <business.document.header.types:errorCode>00007</business.document.header.types:errorCode>
            <business.document.header.types:serverityCode>Error</business.document.header.types:serverityCode>
            <business.document.header.types:description>Message previously processed but no valid reponse is available</business.document.header.types:description>
          </business.document.header.types:messageEvent>
        </business.document.header.types:messageEvents>
      </business.document.header.types:businessDocumentHeader>
    </external.bz1:reply>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/django_projects/ecr/businessNames/views.py" in externalBz1
  19.     result = doExternalBz1(test)
File "/django_projects/ecr/businessNames/models.py" in doExternalBz1
  75.     result = client.service.externalBz1(header, body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py" in __call__
  542.             return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py" in invoke
  602.         result = self.send(soapenv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py" in send
  643.                 result = self.succeeded(binding, reply.message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py" in succeeded
  678.             reply, result = binding.get_reply(self.method, reply)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.6.egg/suds/bindings/binding.py" in get_reply
  145.         replyroot = sax.parse(string=reply)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.6.egg/suds/sax/parser.py" in parse
  136.             sax.parse(source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py" in parse
  107.         xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py" in parse
  123.             self.feed(buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py" in feed
  211.             self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/handler.py" in fatalError
  38.         raise exception

Exception Type: SAXParseException at /businessNames/externalBz1/1/
Exception Value: <unknown>:1:0: syntax error
```

That's straight from the log, with no mention of the parse error :(

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: The XML is clearly valid. Are you sure it's a SAXParseException? Post the stack trace showing this.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is that what's being passed to the parser is not exactly what you have posted.  Extra whitespace at the start of the buffer might cause this.

Comment: I'm at a complete loss... what I've pasted is what is showing in the log file as being what is received. Is there anyway to remove extra whitespaces in the response before being parsed?

Comment: Can you run the code in a debugger to verify the buffer contents?

Answer (score 4):

I instead of directly passing the result, I did the following and it got rid of the error.

```
sax = suds.sax.parser.Parser()

s_received = str(client.last_received())   # passed "client.last_received()", no error 

s_parse = sax.parse(string=s_received)
```

Instead of something like:

```
x_request = eval(client.service.ListTestAccounts)

result = x_request("1")

sax = suds.sax.parser.Parser()

s_result = str(result)           # passed "result", generated error

s_parse = sax.parse(string=s_result)
```

Hope this helped.